# Git progress watch while pulling / fetching

Tags: git, git-fetch

Here is my problem:

When I'm doing pull/fetch of some big repository i want to show progress somewhere else than in console (for example on website)
I know that in git 1.7.1.1 there is option --progress but I can't use this version and must stay with 1.6.0.4

does anybody have idea how to watch git fetch/pull progress (for example how to extract current percent of download)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how this could be done, since the --progress option has been implemented in `upload-pack.c`

And [`git upload-pack` mentions](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-upload-pack.html)

> Invoked by `git fetch-pack`, learns what objects the other side is missing, and sends them after packing.
>
> **This command is usually not invoked directly by the end user**.
> The UI for the protocol is on the `git fetch-pack` side, and **the program pair is meant to be used to pull updates from a remote repository**.
> For push operations, see git send-pack.

So if the server doesn't send back this kind of data, I don't know how to extract it directly, except by checking out this comment in `upload-pack.c`

```
    /* We read from pack_objects.err to capture stderr output for
     * progress bar, and pack_objects.out to capture the pack data.
     */
```

If you have access to `pack_objects.err` on the server side, you might be able (*maybe*) to get some informations from that.